# How to find if two distinct accounts are being accessed from same computer but using different browser?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address, user-tracking

I couldn't track a machine using ip-address because I usually get proxy server address

```
public static String GetIP()
{
    String ip = 
        HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return ip;
}
```

Are there any other ways to track a machine correctly?

Comment: Even the mac address can be cloned. I don't think there's a 100% reliable solution for this, even if you install some client-side code.

Comment: @Leo let's not consider about mac address cloning.Is it possible to read the mac address of a client ?

Comment: if the client allow some signed applet to work outside the sandbox, I guess so.

Comment: What is your use-case? Because I could have two computers on the same network accessing your site with two different accounts.  What problem are you trying to solve or prevent?

Comment: @BlackFrog My use case is two accounts should not be allowed to login from a single computer using different browsers as well.

Comment: @Leo do you have any sample for what you are suggesting because I am more willing to experiment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading ip-address is the only way But with that also you can't trace exactly due to Network address translators,Proxy servers and VPN servers etc.

You have to understand this its privacy issue

Even in iOS also they have forbidden to read UDID right from iOS 7 as it infringes users privacy

Hope this solves your problem